# No Sound / Choppy sound Creative HD Titanium & 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, sound

I'm new to Ubuntu, I set up my double boot three days ago ! I managed to figure everything out except for the sound. I'm using a Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium HD. I typed the command that allowed me to select analog devices in the sound properties. I see the name of my sound card but when I do the tests ("Front left - Front right") I only hear one word out of the two or nothing at all. I know I probably need to copy/paste some info from my system so that you can help me. I just don't know what you need ! Please let me know and I'll post it asap. 
Thanks !

Comment: I also have problems with this card. Here's to hoping someone has an idea :)